# Java ArrayList remve element by index doesn't work

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm having a problem with the function remove() from ArrayList.DrawSurface and MyDialog are two classes in my project.myRects is an ArrayList in DrawSurface and it used to be a parameter pass to dialog.I want to use dialog to remove an element in myRects.It run without any error but remove nothing.

`dialog.setRemove(myRects, whichRect);`

MyDialog：

```
public void setRemove(ArrayList list, int i) {
mList = list;
which = i;
this.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pButton:
            mList.remove(which);
            which = -1;
            this.dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.nButton:
            this.dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I try to debug it.myRects and mList have the same address.And I can remove the element in dialog.But when I go back to DrawSurface myRects recovery.I don't know why.What should I do to finish it?

Comment: it means your  primitive `int` does not find the index . Use Wrapper class `Integer` .

Comment: No.It find the index in mList, and remove it.There is no change in myRects in DrawSurface. But mList and myRects are two reference to a same object.

Comment: So you mean its removing but not reflecting ?

Comment: yes. int is a serial number. There is no IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I have solved it.I re-enter the data in ````onWindowFocusChanged()````

Answer (score 0):

You have to use list adapter and call

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

after removing item from list and before closing dialog.

Comment: I am not using the ListView, ArrayList is a collection of objects used to store rectangular objects.I passed the ArrayList as a parameter to the dialog, I try to remove an element in OnClick(), but the debug time found through this line the elements are indeed deleted, but after dialog dismiss the ArrayList has been recover.

Comment: I have solved it.I re-enter the data in ````onWindowFocusChanged()````

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, there are two options for what's going on:

1. You never trigger your OnClick() method which is what actually invokes the `remove()` method of the ArrayList.
2. You are breaking the `mList` reference to `myRects` in the code for `MyDialog` that you're withholding, with a `mList = new (...)` or some other assignment to `mList` that's taking place.

The code you have shown creates a form which likely executes some code before someone does anything to trigger OnClick().

```
public void setRemove(ArrayList list, int i) {
mList = list;
which = i;
this.show();
}
```

The code and the details in the question don't give any information as to what happens between `this.show()` and when you determine that `myRects` did not have the desired element removed. Your issue is most likely one of the two items identified above.

Comment: I have solved it.I re-enter the data in ````onWindowFocusChanged()````